# How do I update conda from 4.10.3 to 4.11.0

Tags: python, r, conda, rgee

I am trying to use run reticulate so that I can use google earth engine in R. After updating my r, my current script is completely useless unless I can figure some issues with it. When I run reticulate::py_install('earthengine-api==####) ( the '### are in place of the actual numbers that identify my account) I get this message:

==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
current version: 4.10.3
latest version: 4.11.0

Please update conda by running

```
$ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

However, when I run what r is telling me to run r doesnt recognize it. How do I update conda anyways?

Comment: Try to restart R session.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is suggesting you update Conda and the command it provides is a shell command, not an R one, which is why it does not work directly in R. Typically, one manages Conda via the shell, but if you only manage it through `reticulate`, then one can use the `reticulate::conda_install` command instead. It should be something like:

```r
reticulate::conda_install(envname="base", packages="conda=4.11", channel="defaults")
```